# Apache 2.4 problems with images

Tags: php, laravel, apache

it turns out that I have a problem with the images. I have tried locally executing php artisan serve and without problems, but when I take the project to an apache server said image does not exist and I cannot obtain it, the apache 2.4 server is running on a win server 2012 locally. The code is the following

```
<?php
$file = 'file:///f:/work/sersoc/photos/' . $user_code . '.jpg';
                             if (file_exists($file)) {
                                 $image = file_get_contents($file);
                                 $image_codes = base64_encode($image);
                             } else {
                                 $image_codes = null;
                             }

?>
```

I tried changing the path to
`$file = 'file://10.10.20.5/work/work/sersoc/photos/' . $user_code . '.jpg';`
This is the ip that refers to the disk that I have on the network where I have all the photos, but nothing changed

Edit:
My VirtualHosts

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs"
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias workturns.com
  #Require all granted
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost workturns.com:80>
  DocumentRoot "C:\Apache24\htdocs\workturns\public"
  ServerName workturns.com
  ServerAlias workturns.com
  <Directory "C:\Apache24\htdocs\workturns\public">
    DirectoryIndex index.php
     Options ExecCGI
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit:
When i use file_get_contents i get the following error
file_get_contents(): remote host file access not supported. But this error only appears when I run on Apache24

Comment: `$file = 'file://10.10.20.5/work/work/sersoc/photos/' . $user_code . '.jpg';` Try removing "file://" for network paths (becuase then it uses http)

Comment: didn't work either

Comment: did you try to change image files owner as www-data or apache, which user execute the service? chown www-data:www-data *.png

Comment: @meta1465 try pasting the link `10.10.20.5/wo.....` in your web browser.. if it works, then it's a fault within apache. If it doesn't, it's a fault in your network

Comment: @JoeyM, this work, but when i call this from my app running in Apache not work. I have no idea what settings I need to do other than the ones I mentioned I did to get this to work.